# scroll snapping Issue

Tags: html, css, scroll-snap

I'm creating a landing page where top section have normal scrolling, followed by a container with scroll snapping enabled followed by a normal scrolling container. But when I have scroll snapping enabled, I cannot move out of the middle container. I can't see top half nor can I see bottom half.

This is the container where scroll snapping is enabled

```css
.scrollcontainer {
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 100vh;
}

.scrollcontainer section {
  height: 100vh;
  scroll-snap-align: start;
}
```

```html
<div class="scrollcontainer">
  <section class="firstpiece">
    <h1>First page</h1>
  </section>
  <section class="secondpiece">
    <h1>Second page</h1>
  </section>
  <section class="thirdpiece">
    <h1>Third page</h1>
  </section>
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```css
html {
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
}

section {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  height: 100vh;
  scroll-snap-align: start;
}
```

```html
<section class="firstpiece">
  <h1>First page</h1>
</section>
<section class="secondpiece">
  <h1>Second page</h1>
</section>
<section class="thirdpiece">
  <h1>Third page</h1>
</section>
```